# how can i bind the json data to labels in c#

Tags: c#, json, json.net

this is my json data:

```
{
  "tappal": {
    "totalTappals": 50,
    "totalRecieved": 48,
    "totalRangaReddy": 11,
    "totalMalkajgiri": 0,
    "totalVikarabad": 16,
    "totalUnSigned": 0
},
```

i tried this: values showing "0"

```
var response3 = await client.GetAsync(path3);
var data3 = await response3.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();                      
var data3tappals = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Tappal>(data3);

lblTotaltappal.Text = data3tappals.totalTappals.ToString();
lbltotaltappalReceived.Text = data3tappals.totalRecieved.ToString();
```

Comment: Well....you've shown source data, your code sample.... but wait - what is wrong with it? What problem have you met - are you getting compile time error, runtime exception or just unintended behaviour? Your "question" lacks question itself...

Comment: and what is the result? what do you expect the result to be? set a breakpoint and step through your code, what are the values of data3tappals?

Comment: your JSON is an object containing a property "tappal", which itself is an object. Your sample is also invalid due to the comma at the end - is that a typo? Assuming so, serializing data3 to type Tappal is unlikely to produce the result you expect. Are you getting any kind of exception or warning? Lastly you've spelled "Received" wrongly in both your JSON and your class.

Comment: i am getting values to "data3". but when i Deserialize, the properties values become ("data3tappals" )  0. i want to get values like : lblTotaltappal.Text=50